# Почему fetch POST-запрос возвращает 404 на localhost / React?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch

Windows 10, localhost:3000 и React, установленный с помощью `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
async function loadData() {
  let url = './index.php';

  let user = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
  };
  
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  });
  

  console.log(response);
}

// <...>

componentDidMount() {
  const res = loadData();
}
```

При post-запросе получаю ошибку 404, запрос:

```
let response = await fetch(url); 
console.log(response.text());
```

отдаёт html-представление index.php, но не возвращаемые этим файлом данные.

Прошу совета, в чем может быть проблема, как её исправить, и где об этом можно прочитать?

Comment: nodejs не запускает php, для этих целей я использую json-server и запускаю его на другой порт

Comment: можно сначала хотя бы браузером посетить указанный адрес и увидеть что показывает, чтобы убедиться что php часть проекта правильно отрабатывает. в инструментах разработчика браузера можно изменить тип запроса и передаваемые данные, чтобы им имитировать работу клиента на реакте. а так же увидеть что и где передает и запрашивает клиент (Ваш проект).